# Copy artifacts from one jenkins101 to another jenkins102

Tags: jenkins

does anybody know any examples of how to copy the a artifact which is archived on jenkins101 to jenkins102 when a job is triggered on jenkins102

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What are jenkins101 and jenkins102? Are those jobs, nodes or different jenkins installation?